# json2typescript serializeObject method returning empty object

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to convert Typescript Contact class back to JSON which is possible according to the documentation for the 'json2typscript' package.

- deserializeObject works fine.
- serializeObject returns an empty obj.

  ```
   map(res => {
    const jsonConvert: JsonConvert = new JsonConvert();
    return jsonConvert.deserializeObject(res, Contact);
  })
  ```

This does not work by returning {}:

```
 try {
  const obj = new JsonConvert().serializeObject(contact);
  console.log(obj);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

This is the class I am trying to map against:

```
@JsonObject('Contact')
export class Contact {

@JsonProperty('id', String, true)
id: string = undefined;

@JsonProperty('created', String, true)
created: string = undefined;

@JsonProperty('updated', String, true)
updated: string = undefined;

@JsonProperty('first_name', String, true)
firstName: string = undefined;

@JsonProperty('last_name', String, true)
lastName: string = undefined;

@JsonProperty('role', String, true)
role: string = undefined;

@JsonProperty('phone', String, true)
phone: string = undefined;

@JsonProperty('email', String, true)
email: string = undefined;

@JsonProperty('notes', String, true)
notes: string = undefined;

@JsonProperty('companies', [Company])
companies: [] = undefined;
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Are you mapping Contact class to json?

Comment: @Doguita that is the idea yes. There are two snake case properties that must be converted back for a PUT to the server.

Comment: I mean using JsonObject and JsonProperty decorators

Comment: @Doguita I updated the question to include the actual class.

Comment: Are you sure all this properties are strings? What is the content of res?

Comment: The content of res is a JSON response from the server. That is not the issue. The problem is getting JSON out of Typescript class of format JsonProperty. https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2typescript

Comment: Misread that part. But I copied you class and it works both ways here. Maybe the problem is in some the contact attributes? If I set the Id as a number, it won't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213790/discussion-between-godhar-and-doguita).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [Pull Request](https://github.com/AppVision-GmbH/json2typescript/pull/126)

If you are using an object that is not a real instance of the mapped class you should pass a second argument to `serializeObject` as a reference class:

```
jsonConvert.serializeObject(contact, Contact);
```

Works on v1.3.0+

Comment: The above implementation found it lates pull request. Anyone using less than "^1.3.0" will not be able to run the above method and do the serialization. Make sure that (contact, Contact) match types. Thanks to @Doguita